# how I can insert a longtable in multipage vertically?

Tags: longtable

I know only the use of `longtable` in LaTeX, but I want to insert this `longtable` vertically.

Comment: what about `\begin{landscape}\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}\end{landscape}`? (you will need `\usepackage{pdflscape}` )

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe better provide a compilable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your problem.